How many kills does it take to research the non-Boss hostiles?
This reddit thread has a comment saying:

[–]Jakey38 2 points 2 years ago
Simple answer Bosses take 10 kills to 100% research.

But how many kills do I need for full research for regular enemies like Kerberons? And what counts as a boss other than the regional bosses like Phrike? Do Infected Scouts count, because they're a random chance spawn?
